# What's the earliest story where a planet's core is a brain?

Tags: history-of

I sent Marvel a synopsis to my sequels series about a planet that uses a brain for a core. Eight years later when I watched *Guardians of the Galaxy 2* for the first time, lo and behold, Marvel was using this theme.  I've seen other Marvel stories with plots that are within my novels.

It is legal to use ideas but this "brain for a planet's core" which is attempting to redesign the universe is a theme/plot. Unfortunately I am unable to sue Marvel because they own billions of dollars and I am a struggling artist.

Are there examples of a story with a brain as a planet's core that might predate both my idea, and GOTG2?

Comment: You *are* aware that the Ego character (a.k.a, the Living Planet, as a planet with a humanoid face) was created in the 1960s in Marvel's comic books, right?

Comment: Most comic creators (and companies) have a policy of not reading unsolcited stories, precisely to avoid this sort of thing. Outside of any material they would have sent you, where would they have seen your novels? Assuming "Joe Hurt" is your actual name, a search of Amazon brings up a Joe Hurt trio, but no books by a Joe Hurt.

Comment: Marvel have a specific policy of ***not reading unsolicited works*** for precisely this reason; "*Marvel does not accept or consider any ideas, creative suggestions, artwork, designs, game proposals, scripts, manuscripts, or similar material unless we have specifically requested it from you.*" - https://www.marvel.com/help/category/17/topic/30

Comment: I sent DC an idea for a film where Superman fights Batman. I was unsurprised to see that they'd failed to credit me for the idea.

Comment: It could be just considered a variation of the [GeniusLoci](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GeniusLoci). Or even stories about haunted houses and the like. Or [Mogo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mogo)...

Comment: To RDFozz &Va;orum- i never claimed published anything Yes big corps do not accept outside submissions but marvel does have a contact e.m. I did send synopsis not entire book. Their attorney wrote back stating, "due to lack of resources we're unable to accept.." This after they made 300 million smackers off Avenger movie. I then wrote a parody about their alleged super heroes mocking them and told Marvel how their super heroes are a bunch of phonies. Marvel then did movie/parody. thanks 4 sharing earliest copyR to planets with brains. My 5 novels uses 40 yrs major inventions in plot.

Comment: planet/brain= characters vie 4 control of planet 2 redesign universe (my plot) Elf using dark matter- my plot except i am using Mr Modem (Man Of dark Energy Matter). Marvel did parody-MY Plot! I have revolutionized entire space industry with major invention. I have a flying saucer that renders ALL air crafts of z world harmless/obsolete. I have a manual ornithopter one pedals to fly like birds and bugs. In my 5 books all inventions r there . I am, in future going to own Marvel. I own this means.

Answer (score 3):

[*When The World Screamed*](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks01/0100031h.html) by Arthur Conan Doyle.

Other living planets:

Yggardis the Tentacled planet:

[image: Comic showing Yggardis the Tentacled planet]

Mogo:

[image: Comic panel showing Mogo]

[The Beast Planet](http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2012/347/9/9/shadow_raiders_beast_planet_by_seekerarmada-d5ny77y.jpg).